# how to fix shadow clipping with transition

Tags: html, css, shadow, clipping

I'm getting this weird issue where the shadow is clipping, but only some of the time. (In chrome, doesn't seem to be happening in Safari)
It seems to be related to `transition`, when I remove it, it stops happening.

clipping with `transition: box-shadow 80ms` (and maybe margin?)
[image: clipping]

without `transition`
[image: unclipped]